# Android Room throws error: Deletion methods must either return void or return int (the number of deleted rows)

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

I'm using Android Room with RxJava

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.1.0-alpha02'
}
```

I need to get Completable from parameterized deletion methods, I thought this feature is added as of 2.1.0? ex.

```
  @Query("DELETE FROM message_table WHERE uid = :id")
  Completable delete(String id);

  @Query("DELETE FROM message_table")
  Completable deleteAll();
```

Still throws error: `Deletion methods must either return void or return int (the number of deleted rows).`

Comment: The release notes have: "Additional Rx Return Types Support: DAO methods annotated with @Insert, @Delete or @Update now support Rx return types Completable, Single<T> and Maybe<T>". No mention of a `DELETE` in a `@Query`, though.

Comment: I think you can't use it like that you need to create it from call back like this `Single.fromCallable` and make the `deleteAll` returns int

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error message is trying to tell:

With `@Query`, you have to change the returned data-type from `Completable` to `int` or `void`.

The `Completable` would need to subscribe to another method, which runs the method of the `Dao`:

```
Completable
  .fromAction(aMethodWhichCallsDao)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
  .subscribe();
```

Or use the `@Delete` annotation, as @Commonsware suggested (in case this works as advertised).

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you need this anymore, but just went into the same thing today and found out that you need to use all these 3 libs to create DAOs methods to return Completable:

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.1'
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.2.1'
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: In case `room-rxjava2` `2.2.1` `stable` fixes this, this should be current answer to the problem. It's the library which provides the bindings, so it might know about `Completable`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler It knows, I just did it yesterday. They updated the libraries. I first used your response, then I saw that there are updates on the libraries and I saw it works. This is why I added the comment. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Yeah, when I get this error, first thing I look is my build.gradle project file.